# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou carregando uma tabela, e fazendo a depuração, ela trás os dados perfeitamente, porém quando vou pegar os dados da tabela referencia na chave estrangeira, ela está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Aqui é como está na minha model:

```
  public int Id { get; set; }
    public Empresa EmpresaProduto { get; set; }
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
```

Carregando no controller:

```
  var produtoempresa = await db.ProdutosEmpresas.Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id).ToListAsync();
```

E aqui é minha tabela:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model.ProdutosEmpresas)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.EmpresaProduto.RazaoSocial</td>
                                    <td>@item.QtdAtual</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Eu tenho uma outra tabela, que foi montada da mesma forma, e carrega os dados da tabela referenciada normal, porém nesta eu não consigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não está dando o include: altere a linha de carregamento das entidades para:

```
var produtoempresa = await db
        .ProdutosEmpresas
            .Include(p => p.ProdutosEmpresas)
        .Where(p => p.ProdutoID == id)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Assim dá certo, mas o estranho, é que eu faço a mesma coisa em outra tabela, e não me retorna este erro, deve ser algo no banco, rs Obrigado.

Comment: Pode ter várias razões Mariana, se a propriedade estiver como virtual, vai carregar por Lazy Loading, caso não esteja marcada com virtual irá carregar somente com o Eager Loading (uso do Include). Aconselho a ler a documentação do EF.